Inexact Approximation Oracles with Multiplicative Error?
I have a linear program (LP) with $n$ variables and $2^m$ constraints:
$$
\min \sum_{i \in [n]} x_i \quad \text{subject to} \quad x_i \geq y_j \quad \forall j \in 2^m, \, i \in [n].
$$
I can compute an inexact separation oracle: given $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, it returns TRUE if all constraints are satisfied, or FALSE along with $y_j$ if there exists $y_j$ such that $x_i < \frac{1}{2} y_j$.
Question: Can I compute an approximation of the optimal solution? Are there references or methods in the literature that address such problems?

Looks like $2^m n$ constraints.
